# Are there two possible triangles in this trigonometry word problem?

Tags: trigonometry

Two planes flying at the same altitude are 3000.0 m apart when they spot a raft on the sea below them. The angles of depression to the raft are 47° and 38° . Find the distance from the raft to the closest plane.

The provided answer to this problem is 1854.0m. This answer is obtained for the triangle obtained when the angle formed at the raft between the two lines of sight to each plane is 95° (i.e., the raft is in between the two planes).

However, it seems to me that another triangle is possible—the one where the angle formed at the raft between the two lines of sight is 9° (i.e., the raft is on the same side of both planes).[image: Problem diagram]

Am I incorrect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct. Actually this doesn't represent a problem since the distance is the same (because of the isosceles triangle or because $\sin (133) = \sin (47)$

Comment: @RickSanchez can you elaborate? When I use the sine law to calculate the distance from plane 2 to the raft in the triangle to the left I obtain 11806.8m.

Comment: Actually your interpretation I think is correct.   Unless the text specifically states the planes are flying toward each other and they both say the raft in front of them, I'd assume both planes are flying in the same direction and they see the raft in front of them.  Actually in three D space we could make a whole range of interpetations.

Comment: @RickSanchez as the distance between the two planes is fixed at 3000 m.  The two triangles will give different (but proportional) results.

Comment: Yes you're right, I misread the problem.

Comment: There seems to be an assumption that the boat and two planes are in the same vertical plane (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "when they spot a raft" would imply that the raft is in front of both pilots. However, this would allow either triangle depending on whether the pilots are flying in the same or opposite directions.

Or, for that matter if they are flying on the same line at all. We could have the pilots flying along, let us say, perpendicular lines in three-dimensional space, in which case you would use spherical trigonometry to solve for the angle at the raft and then get the sides of the planar triangle. We theoretically have a continuous range of possible triangles!

The book should have specified that the pilots were flying directly towards each other.